# Jquery validation is not working chrome version- 4.0.249.30

Tags: jquery

jquery validation is not working in chrome (4.0.249.30) for a external site,But it works for our local machine.

Comment: Please post more information - there is not much anyone can do with this in its current form.

Comment: Code? we can't help you if you don't post any code

Comment: Chrome automatically keeps itself up to date. Why not upgraded to 8.0.552.215 ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,I can`t get any solution.But it worked after re-installation of Chrome (4.0.249.30)

Thank you All